# The if condition does not work as expected in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been having some troubles with this code as the if condition cannot be true and always executes the else condition instead.

can you help
`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry_1 =Entry(root, width = 20)
entry_1.pack()
entry_1.insert(0, "Choose Your Number ")


def m():
    answer = entry_1.get().strip()
    if answer == 5 :
        mylabel = Label(root, text = "YOU WIN!")
        mylabel.pack()
    else :
        mylabel = Label(root, text = "YOU LOST!")
        mylabel.pack()


mybutton = Button(root, text = 'PLAY', command = m)
mybutton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: try `print(type(answer))` is could be string... so `'5'`!=`5`

Comment: `entry_1.get().strip()` returns an `str`. Try changing it to `if answer == '5':`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any user input is a string, so you need to convert to an Integer.

Try this code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry_1 =Entry(root, width = 20)
entry_1.pack()
entry_1.insert(0, "Choose Your Number ")


def m():
    answer = int(entry_1.get().strip())
    if answer == 5 :
        mylabel = Label(root, text = "YOU WIN!")
        mylabel.pack()
    else :
        mylabel = Label(root, text = "YOU LOST!")
        mylabel.pack()


mybutton = Button(root, text = 'PLAY', command = m)
mybutton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```